# A Basic Authentication using Express JS

Tags: javascript, express, curl, localhost

I am trying to do a basic authentication with Username and Password using Express JS. The issue I am facing is that, I will want to use an if statement inside an app.use() function but it seem not to return anything. Find code snippet below and the output am getting

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

app.get('/protected', (req,res)=>{
app.use(basicAuth({authorizer: myAuthorizer}))

function myAuthorizer(username, password){
    const userMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(username, 'admin')
    const passwordMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(password, 'admin')

    if(userMatches == 'admin' && passwordMatches == 'admin'){
        res.send("Welcome, authenticated client");
    }else{
        res.send("401 Not authorized");
    }
}});
app.listen(8080, ()=> console.log('Web Server Running on port 8080!'));
```

When I do curl to the localhost server, I get an empty reply from the server.
Find image below and how to go about it.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, You [should study Middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

function myAuthorizer(username, password) {
    const userMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(username, 'admin')
    const passwordMatches = basicAuth.safeCompare(password, 'admin')

    return userMatches && passwordMatches
}

app.use(basicAuth({ authorizer: myAuthorizer }))

app.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
    
    res.send("Welcome, authenticated client");

});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('Web Server Running on port 8080!'));
```

Comment: How will I include the other condition in the if statement if the user Does not curl the right credentials. How do I factor in that

Comment: You must [configure the authentication](https://gist.github.com/aliensanderdiaz/873a79fd85a02c97bdf49a5543414070)